# Не происходит выход из рекурсии

Tags: java, рекурсия

сделал попытку написания метода для поиска квадратного корня. вроде бы все правильно сделал, но при запуске выдает ошибку:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at hello.Sqrt.midIter(Sqrt.java:23)
    at hello.Sqrt.midIter(Sqrt.java:23)
    at hello.Sqrt.midIter(Sqrt.java:23)
    at hello.Sqrt.midIter(Sqrt.java:23)
    at hello.Sqrt.midIter(Sqrt.java:23)
```

код программы следующий:

```
 public static double middler(double arg1, double arg2){//находит число, стоящее в средине диапазона заданных в аргументах значениях
    double res = (arg2+(arg1-arg2)/2);
    return res;
}

/**/


private static double midIter(double sqr, double app, double low){//метод уменьшает диапазон (как в двоичном поиске) пока квадрат средины диапазона не будет входить в пределы погрешности
    double mid = middler(app, low);//нахождение средины диапазона
    double sq=mid*mid;//возведения средины диапазона в квадрат
    boolean ss = ((sqr-0.01d)<sq && sq<(sqr+0.01d));//проверка вхождения квадрата в диапазон допустиых значений
    if(ss)//если квадрат входит в диапазон допустимых значений, возвращается найденное число
        return mid;
    else{//если же нет, диапазон, заданный аргументами, делится на две части и происходит поиск в более подходящей из них
        if(sq>sqr)

            return midIter(sqr, sq, low);//вызывется этот же метод (рекурсия) с новыми значениями диапазона
        else
            return midIter(sqr,app, sq);//вызывется этот же метод (рекурсия) с новыми значениями диапазона
    }
}
public static double sQrt(double arg){//метод, который вызывается первым и вызывает все остальные. в качестве аргумента принимает число, корень которого нужно найти
    double apBound = arg;//верхняя граница
    double lBound = 0f;//нижняя граница
    double m = middler(apBound, lBound);
    if(m*m==arg)
        return m;
    else{
        return midIter(arg, apBound, lBound);
    }
}
```

Comment: Может, слишком глубокая рекурсия происходит? Стек же не резиновый.

Comment: @zed, а как увеличить стек или уменьшить глубину рекурсии?

Comment: Увеличить стек можно вот так: http://codeforces.com/blog/entry/166?locale=ru а глубину рекурсии можно изменить только изменив логику вашего алгоритма. Но для начала, не плохо бы узнать текущую глубину рекурсии http://www.cyberforum.ru/java/thread822287.html

Comment: Автор, вам поставлена задача использовать рекурсию или нет? Если нет, то автор книги "Совершенный код" Стив Макконнелл отозвался про рекурсию примерно в таком духе: рекурсия - очень мощное средство разработки, и требуется всегда рассмотреть альтернативные версии, и использовать их, если можно обойтись без рекурсии. К слову, использование рекурсии для вычисления факториала - не есть оптимальным вариантом.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Мне кажется, ваш метод будет гораздо быстрее сходиться, и, соответственно, не понадобится такой глубокий стек, если вы напишите соответствующую часть кода следующим образом:

```
if(sq>sqr)
        return midIter(sqr, mid, low);
    else
        return midIter(sqr,app, mid);
```

То есть замените `sq` на `mid`. Тогда при каждой итерации отрезок будет уменьшаться вдвое.

Вообще, если честно, у меня есть опасения, что если оставить все как есть, то корень вообще может не найтись, так как отрезок вообще может не уменьшаться. И тогда никакое увеличение стека не поможет.

Обычно такие задачи решают без рекурсии, используя цикл `while`().